# Error in net/ftp while using sendcmd function

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I used net/ftp for accessing the remote files. I need to execute the command and get the result from remote machine. How can I do this??

I have tried the following way,

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ftp'
require 'fileutils'

URL = 'ip'
username = 'name'
passwd = "pass"

directory = 'path'
filename = 'file'

  ftp=Net::FTP.new
  ftp.connect(URL,21)
  ftp.login(username,passwd)
  ftp.chdir(directory)
  ftp.sendcmd("fuser filename")
  ftp.close

It throw the following error,

   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:243:in `getresp': 500 Unknown command. (Net::FTPPermError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:264:in `sendcmd'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftp.rb:262:in `sendcmd'
        from connection.rb:20
```

How can I solve this error?? Please give some suggestion on this..

Answer (score 0):

As I've just found the answer to your question after I've found your question:

To issue site specific commands, add a "SITE" in front of the command:

```
ftp.sendcmd("SITE fuser #{filename}")
```